# Change docstring when inheriting but leave method the same

Tags: python, inheritance, python-sphinx

I'm building an HTTP API and I factored out a lot of code into a superclass that handles requests to a collection of objects. In my subclass, I specify what database models the operation should work on and the superclass takes care of the rest.

This means that I don't need to re-implement the get, post, etc. methods from the superclass, however, I want to change their docstrings in the subclass so that I can have some documentation more specific to the actual model the endpoint is operating on.

What is the cleanest way to inherit the parent class's functionality but change the docstrings?

Example:

```
class CollectionApi(Resource):
    """Operate on a collection of something.
    """
    class Meta(object):
        model = None
        schema = None


    def get(self):
        """Return a list of collections.
        """
        # snip

    def post(self):
        """Create a new item in this collection.
        """
        # snip

class ActivityListApi(CollectionApi):
    """Operations on the collection of Activities.
    """
    class Meta(object):
        model = models.Activity
        schema = schemas.ActivitySchema
```

Specifically, I need `ActivityListApi` to have `get` and `post` run like in `CollectionApi`, but I want different docstrings (for automatic documentation's sake).

I can do this:

```
    def get(self):
        """More detailed docs
        """
        return super(ActivityListApi, self).get()
```

But this seems messy.

Comment: I don't understand it, if the methods do the same thing, why do they need different docstrings? Or, to put it differently, won't the base class users benefit from extended docstrings as well?

Comment: Since this is an API, I thought it would be helpful for the child classes to have, e.g. example requests and responses. Since the specific request and response varies depending on exactly what kind of resource is being operated on, you can't have that kind of detail in the base class.

Comment: Add the detail to the class docstring.

Comment: That's an option, but there are two shortcomings. 1. This means I'm documenting as many as 4 methods in one docstring, which is not very user friendly. 2. I'm using a package that automatically documents http endpoints, so I won't be taking advantage of its capability if I stuff all the documentation into the class docstring.

Comment: How about a "private" \_get that does the actual work, just on super?  You then have 2 separate get that call it, but they each get their docstring.  Sure, folks might wonder why this arrangement, but not not much more than a fancier solution.

Comment: That's not a bad idea, marginally cleaner than my `super`. I'll see if anybody else has ideas.

Comment: @JLPeyret: if you post that as an answer, I'll be happy to accept it

Comment: @Plasma - cool, added.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
class CollectionApi(Resource):
    """Operate on a collection of something.
    """

    def _get(self):
        """actual work... lotsa techy doc here!

           the get methods only serve to have something to hang 
           their user docstrings onto
        """

        pass

    def get(self):
        """user-intended doc for CollectionApi"""
        return self._get()

class ActivityListApi(CollectionApi):

    def get(self):
        """user-intended doc for ActivityListApi"""
        return self._get()
```